High CPU usage by systemd-udevd on charging
I run Arch Linux on my HP Victus 15-fb0xxx laptop. When I charge it, the temperature rises by a lot(from 40C idle to 50C).
Most issues related to this seem to be caused by bluetooth or usb and generally are fixed by disabling the device or removing and reconnecting the usb, but I am not sure how to proceed with this.
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[360.328951] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [360.447290] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
KERNEL[361.350904] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [361.469615] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
KERNEL[362.374285] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [362.489815] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
KERNEL[363.401234] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [363.519942] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
KERNEL[364.424461] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)
UDEV  [364.542906] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0 (power_supply)

The following message is repeated when charging however there is no output when idle, so it is clear that this is causing rise in temperature(the cpu usage is higher too)

does this happen on other operating systems as well? Because charging the battery is indeed one of the most heat-intense things you'll do in a laptop. And 50°C – where was that measured? If it was on the outlet of the CPU fan, sure, one might look into that, but if it's the battery pack temperature, this is as designed.

And the fact that these things appear in your log at a 1 s interval is not problematic at all – this is just udev telling things that might be interested (like the battery symbol in your desktop environment) that the battery has now been charged to so and so many percent.

@MarcusMüller I'll check it in windows(I've dualbooted) and 50C was measured in htop cpu temperature, not battery pack's. Also to the second, I guess, but otherwise it has no output only when charging. Also the cpu usage change is not so much, on idle 0 and now around 2%. EDIT: It has charged fully, so I'll drain it and then test later on windows

50°C CPU temperature is absolutely not anything even resembling a problem; CPUs work fine up to roughly 100 °C, so this is a perfectly acceptable temperature. Remember that the CPU is in the same tight enclosure as the battery and the battery charging system. No need to test on windows – there's simply no problem here.
